# Raspberry Pi GPIO Hat

Tags: gpio, python

I've got this Raspberry PI GPIO [expansion hat][1] attached to a Raspberry PI 3b and have a question. Even though the terminal blocks are well labeled, I don't think I understand what pin numbers of PI they are referring to? Like I don't see GPIO1, etc. What a really need is documentation showing the pinout number of the PI to the label on the terminals.

Or am I just overthinking it?

Thanks in advance for any help, suggestions.

Doug

Comment: this should help https://pinout.xyz/

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for this table (notice the Header column )

[image]

Original documentation here
https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/pins/

Comment: Thanks very much for this Roman, looks great to me!

Comment: This is misleading info.  The OP stated he's working with an RPi 3B and you're showing the pin header of an old RPi 1.  The pins of a 26-pin header for the RPi 1 have a totally different layout compared to the 40-pin header of the RPi 2 and later versions.  As mentioned in another reply, [pinout.xyz](https://pinout.xyz/) is the place to be.